# Should supervised actors in Akka receive messages directly or via its supervisor?

Tags: akka, akka.net, actor-model

I recently watched a [great video by Riccardo Terrell about Akka.NET and F#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RiWXo_5CAvg) but the question I am going to ask is related to Akka in general. I was puzzled with a part where he discusses supervisor and supervision strategy on error. In his examples clients send messages to supervisor that forwards them to a worker actor by calling worker.Tell(msg, mailbox.Sender()). I wonder how common is such practice. In our system there are a few places where a client first Ask a supervisor to obtain a worker instance and then make Tell calls directly to a worker. I am not happy about using Ask but in our case we need worker affinity, i.e. messages from the same client may need to be routed to the same worker so giving a client a worker instance simplifies this. But again, Ask is bad. So in case of supervised actors, are they supposed to receive messages via the supervisor (to avoid Ask) or "it depends"?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be is use [hashing pool](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers) when using simple hasing function, so then you can eliminate sending back references to asker.

```
new ConsistentHashingPool(5).WithHashMapping(o =>
{
   if (o is IHasCustomKey)
       return ((IHasCustomKey)o).Key;

   return null;
});
```

Any comments welcome!